# Sharepoint Designer SPList option "Hide from browser" in code?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, splist, hidden

When I hide the list using

```
list.Hidden = true;
```

It's hidden from the Quick Launch and it's also hidden from the Sharepoint Designer.

I'm rather interested in a useful feature for lists in Sharepoint Designer called "Hide from browser". Can this option be set from code?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen other posts where users claim that [SPList.Hidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.hidden.aspx) is somehow different from SharePoint Designer's option `Hide from browser`.

It is my belief that both the code approach and the designer setting are one and the same.

> A hidden list does not appear on the Documents and Lists page, Quick
>   Launch bar, the Modify Site Content page, or the Add Column page as an
>   option for lookup fields.

A potential reason why a list no longer appears in SharePoint Designer after you mark it as hidden is usually when the permission level for your user account do not allow you to see hidden lists. This happens for example, when you are `site owner` (full control), but not site collection administrator.

Comment: I *am* a site collection admin, and a list I 'hid from browser' earlier today in SPD2013 is now nowhere to be found in SPD!

Comment: I stand by. If you run list.Hidden = $true followed $list.Update(), the "Hide list from browser" is immediately checked. Not sure what are the exact permission levels required to see lists even when hidden.

Comment: Egads. Found them finally.

Answer (score -1):

Actually via SharePoint Designer you do have an option to "show" again the list. The operation you mentioned, performed via code, does exactly that!

How to open hidden list and un-hide it in Designer:

1)      Open SharePoint designer 2010.

2)      Click the “All Files” folder at the bottom in left pane.

3)      Right click your hidden list from “All Files -> Lists” folder and choose property.

4)      Now you have your hidden list open in SPD.

5)      In List settings-> General Settings: Un-check the “Hide from browser” and save.

Comment: What I want to achieve is the opposite: is there a code equivalent to Designer's "Hide from browser" that works exactly like the Designer option?

Comment: You mean that setting "Hidden" to False (followed by a call to Update), doesn't show up again??

Comment: Do people even read the question?