# 'All Files' missing from SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365

So 'All files' button is missing for me in SP Designer. I checked [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206575/sharepoint-designer-all-files-missing) but my admin says he can't see any sharepoint designer settings - he can just enable it. Is it a limitation of Office 365 we're on that you cannot do it? Also i found information that one needs to be a whole site collection admin to actually get 'all files' unlocked. Anyone knows if its like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm **All Files** appears just fine on Office 365 sites.

I think some of the links/options in there are security trimmed and will only appear if you are a site collection administrator.

See also

[Sharepoint Designer SPList option "Hide from browser" in code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57511/sharepoint-designer-splist-option-hide-from-browser-in-code)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have to ask the admin to either make me a full admin or do this for me somehow.